# Spring Thymeleaf twice form submit Error 400

Tags: java, spring, forms, thymeleaf

i have a thymeleaf form that can validate data from the database through spring controller, the data validation works fine, but when i want to validate with different data after validation it give me an Error 400, there's no error in the stack trace, so i don't know how how to fix this, maybe because of my bad logic, because i'm newbie at this..

here's the form

```
<form th:name="memberRkiForm" id="memberRkiForm" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${formResult}"
      method="POST">
  <div>
    <table id="form">

      <tr>
        <td colspan="7" height="40"><img class="formlogo"
                                         th:src="@{/resources/img/docicon.png}">
          <h3 class="formHeader"><b><u>REGISTER MANUAL</u></b></h3></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Provider Name </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" th:value="${providerId}" name="providerId" style="width:275px;"
                 readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden"> </input>
          <input type="text" th:value="${providerName}" name="providerName" style="width:275px;"
                 readonly="readonly"> </input>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Member Card Number* </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="cardNumber" th:field="*{cardNumber}"
                 onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                 style="width:190px; display: inline;"> </input>
          <input id="checkCardNum" class="default-button" type="submit" style="display: inline;"
                 value="Validasi">
        </td>
        <td width="500">
          <div class="error" style="display:inline;color:red;">
            <p id="cardNumError" style="margin-left:15px;" th:text="${cardNumError}"></p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Member Name </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" th:value="${memberName}" name="memberName" style="width:275px;"
                 readonly="readonly"> </input>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Date Of Birth </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" th:value="${birthday}" name="birthday" style="width:275px;"
                 readonly="readonly"> </input>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><label>Client Name </label></td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" th:value="${clientName}" name="clientName" style="width:275px;"
                 readonly="readonly"> </input>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Admission Date </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input id="datepicker" type="text"
                 style="margin-top:4px;width:230px;display:inline-block;"/>
          <span class="calendarbox"><img th:src="@{/resources/img/calendar.png}" height="25"
                                         width="35"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><label>Claim Service* </label></td>
        <td><label>:</label></td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" th:value="${selectServiceIsEnabled}" name="selectServiceIsEnabled"
                 style="width:275px;" readonly="readonly" hidden="hidden"> </input>
          <select id="selectservice" th:field="*{caseCategoryList}" class="selectcss"
                  style="width:275px;margin-left: 5px;" disabled="disabled">
            <option th:each="case : ${caseCategoryList}" th:value="${case.caseCategoryId}"
                    th:text="${case.caseCategoryName + ' - ' + case.caseCategoryCode}"></option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td width="500">
          <span class="error" style="display: inline;color:red;"><p id="select_error"></p></span>
        </td>
        <td class="sep"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr colspan="7" class="jumper"></tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="addMember" class="remodal-confirm" type="submit" name="action"
                 value="Register"/>
          <input class="remodal-cancel" type="reset" value="Clear"/>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

when validate button is clicked, the form action goes to a spring controller that check the card number to the database (checkCardNum), then if the data validation return true, the form will be automatically filled by the data that related to the card number, after the form's filled with the data, i want to check validation with another card number (different from the first validated card number), but it give me an error 400.

here's my controller

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('"+ACLConstant.MENU_REGISTRATIONMEMBERRKI+"')")
@RequestMapping(value="/member-rki-form",method={RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST} )
public String memberrkiform(Model model, HttpServletRequest  request, @ModelAttribute("formResult") MemberRkiForm formResult){


    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserAuth userAuth = (UserAuth)auth.getPrincipal();

    String[] cols = {"username", "deletedStatus"};
    Object[] values = {userAuth.getUserName(), 0};

    Users user = userService.findUserByColsAndValues(cols, values);

    int userid = user.getUserId();


    Users currentUser = userService.findUserByPK(userid);

    Provider provider = currentUser.getProvider();

    model.addAttribute("providerId", provider.getProviderId());
    model.addAttribute("providerName", currentUser.getFirstName()); 
    model.addAttribute("cardNumber", formResult.getcardNumber());
    model.addAttribute("cardNumError", formResult.getErrorMsg());
    model.addAttribute("memberName", formResult.getMemberName());
    model.addAttribute("birthday", formResult.getBirthday());
    model.addAttribute("clientName", formResult.getClientName());
    model.addAttribute("caseCategoryList", formResult.getCaseCategoryList());
    model.addAttribute("selectServiceIsEnabled", formResult.getSelectServiceIsEnabled());

    return "memberrki/member-rki-form";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/checkCardNum",method={RequestMethod.GET , RequestMethod.POST})
public String checkCardNum(@ModelAttribute("formResult") MemberRkiForm formResult, Model model, HttpServletRequest  request, RedirectAttributes redirectFormData){

    String errorMsg = "";

    String cardNumber = formResult.getcardNumber();

    if(cardNumber==null || cardNumber==""){

        errorMsg="Card Number Data Is Required";
    }
    else{

        String[] cols = {"currentCardNumber", "deletedStatus" , "subscriptionStatus"};
        Object[] values = {formResult.getcardNumber(), 0 , 1}; 
        Member member = memberService.findMemberByColsAndValues(cols, values);

        if(member==null){

            errorMsg="Member Not Found";
        }
        else{
            Member validatedMember = memberService.findMemberByPK(member.getMemberId());
            Client validatedMemberClient = validatedMember.getClient();

            formResult.setMemberName(validatedMember.getFirstName());
            formResult.setBirthday(validatedMember.getBirthday().toString());
            formResult.setClientName(validatedMemberClient.getClientName());

            MemberProductSearchParams memberProductParams = new MemberProductSearchParams();
            memberProductParams.setMember(validatedMember);
            memberProductParams.setDeletedStatus(0);
            memberProductParams.setSubscriptionStatus(1);

            Page<MemberProduct> memberProductPage  = memberService.findMemberProductListing(memberProductParams, null);
            List<MemberProduct> memberProductLists = memberProductPage.getContent();


            if(memberProductPage==null || memberProductLists==null){
                /*System.out.println("NO PRODUCT FOUND");*/
                errorMsg="NO PRODUCT AVAILABLE";
            }
            else{
                List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
                List<CaseCategory> caseCategoryList = new ArrayList<CaseCategory>();

                for(int i=0; i<memberProductLists.size(); i++){
                String[] productCols = {"productId", "deletedStatus"};
                Object[] productValues = {memberProductLists.get(i).getProduct().getProductId(), 0}; 
                Product products = productService.findProductByColsAndValues(productCols, productValues);
                productList.add(products);

                String[] caseCategoryCols = {"caseCategoryId", "deletedStatus"};
                Object[] caseCategoryValues = {productList.get(i).getCaseCategory().getCaseCategoryId(), 0};
                CaseCategory caseCategories = caseCategoryService.findCaseCategoryByColsAndValues(caseCategoryCols, caseCategoryValues);
                caseCategoryList.add(caseCategories);

                }

                formResult.setCaseCategoryList(caseCategoryList);

            }


            formResult.setSelectServiceIsEnabled("true");
        }
    }

    formResult.setErrorMsg(errorMsg);
    formResult.setcardNumber(cardNumber);

    redirectFormData.addFlashAttribute("formResult", formResult);
    formResult = new MemberRkiForm();

    return "redirect:/memberrki/member-rki-form";
  }
}
```

maybe someone here can help me to solve the problem,
Thx in advance.. (sorry for my bad english)